# Create a vector of objects that satisfy a concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to create a vector of different types of objects that all satisfy a given concept. My current attempt is something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Foo = requires(T t) {
// constraints...
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> getFooVector();
```

I get that `Foo` is not a complete type, and I think I would have to use type erasure to make this work, but I am not quite sure how I would go about that. How could I make something like this work?

Comment: Do the types share a common polymorphic base? Is the full list of types known in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want '`template<Foo Bar> std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> getFooVector()`. A concept is not a concrete type. It is really a disguised template. You're writing a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to create a vector of different types of objects

This, strictly speaking is impossible, in the sense that all the objects that a `std::vector<T>` can hold, must all be of type `T`.

Whether that `T` is a pointer (smart or not) and so can, in turn, point to entities of different type, that's another story.

So I guess what you want can be obtained in two similar but not so similar ways:

- If you don't know upfront the types that you want to make a collection of, go for

  ```cpp
  struct Foo {
    /* the interface all Foo must satisfy, e.g. ... */
    virtual int f(int) = 0;
  };
  struct Bar : Foo {
    virtual int f(int) override;
  };
  struct Baz : Foo {
    virtual int f(int) override;
  };
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> getFooVector();
  ```

  so in `getFooVector`'s body you can push as many objects of classed *inheriting* from `Foo` as you want.
  In this case, the constraint you wanted to enforce via concept, is enforced via inheritance: if `Foo` declares a pure `virtual` method, the derived classes must override it, i.e. they have to implement that behavior.
- If you do know the types upfront, you can use `std::variant`

  ```cpp
  std::vector<std::variant<Bar,Baz>> getFooVector();
  ```

  Now, if you really want `Bar` and `Baz` to be constrained to implement some common interface, I guess you can still make them inherit from a common base, but probably the compiler will be able to avoid any virtual indeirection, which is good.
- Also remember that if the types have just a very simple interface, e.g. one method (`int(int)` for simplicity below), you could also give a try to a not-my-inheritance approach, by baking the virtuality in a library type named `std::function`:

  ```cpp
  struct Foo {
    std::function<int(int)> const& f;
  };
  auto foo1 = Foo{[](int i){ return i*2; }};
  auto foo2 = Foo{[](int i){ return i*3; }};
  ```

  where `foo1` and `foo2` are truly of type `Foo`, but behave pretty much the same way as an instance of `Baz` and one of `Bar` in the first bullet respectively.

---

I think concepts are the wrong tool for your usecase.

Comment: not-my-inheritance :D like this term

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, ahah, it means that I don't really know how the inside of `std::function` works, but I guess it uses similar tools as inheritance (which "desugars" to orthodox usage of `void*` during compilation?)

Comment: Type erasure deserves a mention.

Comment: @JeffGarrett, doesn't `std::function` use type erasure?

Answer (score 1):

> I get that Foo is not a complete type...

A concept is not type at all. A concept is named set of requirements that can be used to contraint template arguments.

If you make `getFooVector` a template you can constraint the types that can be used to instantiate it via the concept:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
concept Foo = requires(T t) { t,t; };

template <Foo T>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> getFooVector() { return {}; };

int main() {
    auto x = getFooVector<int>();
}
```

In case you actually want `getFooVector` to return a vector with elements of different type (that all satisfy the concept) then this turns out to be a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Because merely defining the concept doesnt achieve much to construct such a vector.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution to the stated problem is type erasure.

To make a concrete example, let's add a few requirements in the concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept Foo = requires(const T ct, T t, int x) {
    { ct.get() } -> std::same_as<int>;
    t.set(x);
};
```

Our goal is to create a type which satisfies the concept but which can hold any type which satisfies the concept:

```
class AnyFoo {
public:
    template<Foo T>
    AnyFoo(T t) : impl_(std::make_unique<Impl<T>>(std::move(t))) {}

    int get() { return impl_->get(); }
    void set(int x) { return impl_->set(x); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<BaseImpl> impl_;
};
static_assert(Foo<AnyFoo>);
```

Clearly, we can create a vector of `AnyFoo`. It is a single concrete type. It can hold any type satisfying `Foo` and it provides the interface from `Foo`.

It does this by indirection using the language facility of inheritance:

```
struct BaseImpl {
    virtual int get() const = 0;
    virtual void set(int x) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Impl : BaseImpl {
    T t;
    int get() const override { return t.get(); }
    void set(int x) override { t.set(x); }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qsf4E87he